# Непонятна логика

Tags: python

```
i = 0
save = []
while i <= 9:
    arr = int(input(("Введите число:")))
    save += [arr]
    i += 1
def positive_sum(arr):
    for i in arr:
        if i < 0:
            arr.remove(i)
    print(arr)
positive_sum(save)
```

Есть значит такой код, который должен отрицательное число со списка удалить, но какие-то он удаляет, а некоторые отрицательные оставляет почему так?
Вот к примеру что вывелось в конце **[213, 1, 23, 4, 21, -2, -4]** Хотя -2 и -4 не должно быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому что **НИКОГДА НЕ УДАЛЯЙТЕ ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ ДВИГАЯСЬ ПО СПИСКУ**!!!

ошибка многих - вы идете по списку от его начало до конца, но удаляя элемент вы сокращаете его размер и как бы сдвигаетесь еще вперед, в итоге ваша нумерация слетает и возникает ошибка в логике

режьте с помощью `filter`

```
save = list(filter(lambda elem: elem >= 0, save))
```

т.е. вы собираете новый список из элементов старого, которые не меньше 0

ну или можно собрать новый список из старого через `for if`

```
save = [elem for elem in save if elem >= 0]
```

при простых условиях это выглядит короче, чем через `filter`

P.S.

кстати зачем такой изврат?

```
i = 0
while i <= 9:
    arr = int(input(("Введите число:")))
    save += [arr]
    i += 1
```

можно же

```
save = [int(input(("Введите число:"))) for i in range(10)]
```

ну или если не нравится в 1 строку, то

```
for i in range(10):
    save += [int(input(("Введите число:")))]
```

а если числа передать через пробел то вообще можно так:

```
save = list(map(int, input().split()))[:10]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое тебе за помощь, уже не в первый раз выручаешь)
Я очень очень слаб в питоне только изучаю основы

Comment: Indra, вообще когда хочется сделать что-то внутри объекта, перемещаясь при этом по объекту, делать это надо аккуратно, потому что там такая "обратная связь" может возникнуть, что ошибку очень сложно найти, а лучше вообще не делать, поэтому этого не потребуют задачи оптимизации ресурсов - например, лучше собрать новый объект и заменить им старый, чем править старый (например для небольших списков это лучшее решение, когда списки будут размером в миллионы записей, а время исполнение будет критичным, тогда и придется ломать голову над аккуратными оптимизациями)

Comment: Zhihar, можете рассказать для чего в этом коде перед for ставиться elem ?
`save = [elem for elem in save if elem >= 0]`
Догадываюсь, каждый четный элемент который находится в elem будет помещен в список. Так ли это?

Comment: цикл в питоне можно записать в таком виде: `[результат этапа цикла] for [элемент итерируемого объекта] in [итерируемый объект] if [условие]` - в данном случае цикл пройдет по всем элементам итерируемого объекта (в данном случае списка `save`), для каждого этапа будет выполнена проверка (в данном случае `if elem >= 0`) и если проверка будет пройдена успешно, то объект (в данном случае элемент `elem` списка `save`) будет добавлен в результат. В качестве результата мы собираем список, что показываем скобками `[]`, таким образом у нас на выходе получается новый список, но уже с элементами >= 0

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение